# map forward declaration do not change value, it return null

Tags: c++, dictionary, null

Using map inside a class and the separation of its declaration do not change any value and always returned null:

```
//config.hpp

class Config
{
  public:
  std::map<char*, char*>config_map;
  Config();
};

//config.cpp

#include "config.hpp"

Config::Config()
{
  config_map["key1"] = "value1";
  config_map["key2"] = "value2";
}

//main.cpp

#include "config.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Config conf;
  printf("%s - %s", conf.config_map["key1"], conf.config_map["key2"]);

  return 0;
}
```

The output will be "(null) - (null)"

However if the declaration is below of the class, in the same header file this work fine. Why?

Comment: The key of the map is `char*`: the lookup compares pointers, not strings that they point to. So it all depends on whether the compiler chooses to merge identical string literals (which is implementation-defined). If literals are merged, then two instances of `"key1"` are at the same address, and the lookup succeeds; if they aren't, then they aren't and it doesn't. You want to use `std::string` for your map elements, not `char*`.

Comment: @Igor that really should be offered below as an answer.

Comment: this code should not compile (`#include <map>` is missing) and also it uses deprecated assignment of string literal to `char *` which the compiler should warn about